# Getting JQuery result when there's html in front of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that submits with AJAX, but the result has HTML in front of it, and I need to be able to get the word 'success' or 'failure', but with the HTML in front I can't. I'm new to JS, so if there's an easy way to do this, I don't know it, and I haven't found anything on google. At first I tried to strip the HTML tags, which would work if there wasn't anything in the tags already, but there is.

The two function I use for posting are:

```
    public function postStatus() {
        global $dbc;
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['user']));
            $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['postBody']));
            $query = "INSERT INTO `social_posts` (`pUID`,`body`,`date`) VALUES ('$user','$body',NOW())";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            $success = array(
                "status"  =>  "success",
                "message" =>  "You've updated your status"
            );
            echo json_encode($success);
            exit();
        }

    }
    public function postForm(){
        $UID = $_SESSION['uid'];
        echo (
<<<EOD
    <div class="shadowbar">
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <form id="socialPostForm" method="POST" action="/sendPost">
    <textarea id="editor" name="postBody" placeholder="Status Post"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="$UID" name="user" />
    <input class="Link LButton" type="submit" value="&#10004;" name="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function post() {
    $("#socialPostForm").validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // any other options,
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            postBody: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        return $("#socialPostForm").valid();
    },
            success : function(result) {
                var page = $(result);
                var statusText = page.find('#status').text();
                console.log(statusText);

                if(statusText == "success"){
                    $("#alert").html("<div class='alert alert-success'>You've updated your status'</div>");
                }else if(statusText == "failure"){
                    $("#alert").html("<div class='alert alert-"+result.status+"'>"+result.message+"</div>");
                    //$("#alert").show();
                }
           }
});
    }); 
</script>   
EOD
);
    }
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to print the html in response from the page where you are posting your ajax request. and show it in div. For eg : `$("#alert").html(sanitized)`. And print the HTML code in that ajax file `<div class='alert alert-success'>You've updated your status'</div>`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the result of the ajax? The one with the html tag in it

Comment: @AadilKeshwani The result is a whole page, i.e. a whole html page with a title, head and such.

Comment: @surajck Refer to my above comment

Comment: I am using PHP and there on ajax response i only send particular DIV in response you can always customize the response if its on your server or you have the control over the page where you are posting ajax request

Comment: @Core, post a sample of your **PHP** file.

Comment: @phillip100 Okay, done.

Comment: @Core, If this echoes a whole page, then it's something wrong with your API. How do you trigger the `postStatus()` and `postForm()`?  It should be something like: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $your_class->postStatus()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the response  in `$()` and treat it just like it was in the page and extract whatever you need using jQuery methods.

I don't know what page looks like or where the text is located so will assume it is in an element with `id=status`

```
success : function(result)
     var $page = $(result);
     var statusText = $.trim($page.find('#status').text());
     // do something with the statusText

}
```

This is a lot of overkill to return a full page. A simple json response would be lighter.

Comment: I don't know what your html page being returned looks like. You would need to target the correct element to get the text. I just added `$.trim` to make sure no whitespace polluting it either. A far better solution is to send back a simple json response